# how to use docker run in kubernetes cluster with flannel network

Tags: docker, flannel

i have a kubernetes cluster with flannel. It works fine. But when i start a container with `docker run` command, the container cannot reach outside.

```
$ docker run --rm -ti centos:7.3.1611 bash
[root@d8a7d18b312a /]# ping 10.33.46.2
```

*10.33.46.2* is another node in my cluster, and ping failed.

```
ip a show docker0
6: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN
    link/ether 02:42:77:05:f5:6c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:77ff:fe05:f56c/64 scope link
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

it shows my docker0 is down. i know it uses cni for docker container in kubernetes cluster. But i cannot find any available network in

```
docker network list
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
a3bd58929a71        bridge              bridge              local
925a55f8f13d        host                host                local
f0c9234fb13f        none                null                local
```

i have no ideal how to use `docker run` in my cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem on my K8S cluster where my Buildkite agents can't run docker builds because it haven't internet access. I resolved it by simply informing --network=host at the Docker command to use the host network instead of the default bridge network. I don't know if its the correct to do, but, it resolved my problem.